# Redux: Why Normalizr library isn't working?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, normalizr

I'm trying to use [Normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) to [flatten](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) the Redux state. Here are the schema definitions

```
import { normalize, schema } from 'normalizr'

const fooSchema = new schema.Entity('foos')
const barSchema = new schema.Entity('bars')

const fooMemberSchema = new schema.Entity('fooMembers', {
    foo: fooSchema
})
const barMemberSchema = new schema.Entity('barMembers', {
    bar: barSchema
})

 export { fooSchema, barSchema, fooMemberSchema, barMemberSchema }
```

And here is the call to the `normalize` in the `doGet` function

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { normalize } from 'normalizr'
import { Promise } from 'es6-promise'
import querystring from 'querystring'
import { CONTEXT_PATH, API_PATH } from '../properties/Properties'

import { fooSchema, barSchema, fooMemberSchema, barMemberSchema } from '../stores/Schema'

/**
 * Tuomas Toivonen
 * 13.1.2019
 */

// Backend mock for development and debugging purposes
const Api = {

    resources: {
        foo: {},
        bar: {}
    },

    doGet({ uri, config={} }) {
        // TODO: tokenize uri
        let data = Object.values(this.resources[uri])
        console.log(data)
        console.log(normalize(data, [fooSchema]))
        return Promise.resolve({data: data})
    },

    doPost({ uri, entity, config={} }) {
        let id = entity.id
        if (!id) {
            id = guid()
            entity.id = id
        }

        this.resources[uri][id] = entity
        return Promise.resolve({data: entity})
    },

    doPut({ uri, entity, config={} }) {
        Promise.reject({message: "doPut not implemented"})
    },

    doDelete({ uri, entity, config={} }) {
        Promise.reject({message: "doDelete Not implemented"})
    }
}

// Generate dummy data
for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {
    let fooId = guid()
    let barId = guid()

    Api.resources.foo[fooId] = {
        id: fooId,
        value: `Foo ${i}`,
        fooMembers: [
            ...(function*() {
                for (let i=0; i<5; i++)
                    yield { id: guid(), value: `FooMember ${i}` }
                })()
            ]
        }
    Api.resources.bar[barId] = {
        id: barId,
        value: `Bar ${i}`,
        barMembers: [
            ...(function*() {
                for (let i=0; i<5; i++)
                    yield { id: guid(), value: `BarMember ${i}` }
                })()
            ]
        }
}

console.log('Using mock API:')
console.log(Api)

function guid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

export default Api
```

However, it doesn't normalize the the structure as expected. Here are the console log messages:

Payload before normalization:
[image: Payload before normalization]

Payload after normalization:
[image: Payload after normalization]

FooMembers are still nested for some reason. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The schema you're passing in is an array of a single entity that does not have any real definition:

```
const fooSchema = new schema.Entity('foos')
normalize(data, [fooSchema])
```

This means that normalizr thinks it's receiving an array of an entity. And that's it.

It looks like what you are illustrating that you want is have `fooMembers` linked into the `fooSchema`. To do that, you need to define the `fooSchema` correctly:

```
const fooMemberSchema = new schema.Entity('fooMembers'); 
const fooSchema = new schema.Entity('foos', { fooMembers: [fooMemberSchema] });
```